# Why won't PHP 5.2.14 display any errors (even from the command line)?

Tags: configuration, error-handling, php, error-reporting

I have PHP 5.2.10 and PHP 5.2.14 (x86 non-threadsafe Win32 builds) installed on a Windows 2008 R2 server and on Windows 7 64 bit.

For some reason PHP 5.2.14 refuses to show error messages.

Even when I set the following settings in `php.ini` I don't get any errors reported if I use 5.2.14:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

This happens even when running a test script from the command line using `php.exe` with a deliberate syntax error:

> c:\php>`php test.php`

PHP is using the correct `php.ini` file because I can see my settings change when I run `php.exe -i`.

I also notice that `php.exe` in PHP 5.2.14 is very slow to start up.

When I perform the same set of tests using PHP 5.2.10 on the same machines I get error messages reported just fine.

Both of the `php.ini` files are stock (based off of `php.ini-recommended`) but with the `error_reporting` and `display_errors` settings modified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have to enable [`display_startup_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-startup-errors) as well:

```
display_startup_errors  boolean
```

> Even when `display_errors` is on, errors that occur during PHP's startup sequence are not displayed. It's strongly recommended to keep `display_startup_errors` off, except for debugging.

You can also try to lint the file with `c:\php>php -l test.php` to test for syntax errors.

Comment: You learn something new every day. Turns out that PHP wasn't able to load a the SQLite3 extension because the pdo.dll extension (has a dependency on this) wasn't uncommented. With `display_startup_errors` set to off this seemed to cause parsing errors to be swallowed up. Thanks very much.

Comment: Actually...investigating further. Someone has put quotes around the `error_reporting` flags value. That's the real cause. i.e. -`error_reporting = "E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE"`.

Answer (score 11):

I have found this truly annoying, so here's a strategy for checking the syntax from the command line:

1. Don't load the ini file.
2. Turn on display_errors and display_startup_errors explicitly.

`php -n -l -d display_errors -d display_startup_errors path/to/your/phpfile.php`

```
$ php -h 
-n               No php.ini file will be used
-l               lint, syntax checking only
-d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
```

Comment: there's a little typo in display_errors flag, despite that this is the best answer

Answer (score 8):

I'm running a later PHP (5.4.24), but these other answers lack the [`-d` option I found exemplified elsewhere](http://blog.xoundboy.com/?p=532) that makes PHP display intelligible parsing errors when running from the command line:

```
php -d display_errors test.php
```

This is the best answer to the question I was googling. Running the linter with `-l` only tells you "Errors parsing foo.php".

Comment: I use this as an alias `alias phprun="php -d display_errors"`

Answer (score 3):

Lately, I had to work on someone else's project... Not being able to debug, I had no choice but to check for this:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

So, check on your source code. Search for something like this: "error_reporting(0);".

Once you've found it, comment it!!!

Normally, you don't have to put that in the source code, but in the *php.ini* file.

Comment: Better yet, add a way to turn it off during (and only during) development. Those error messages can tell would-be hackers a lot about your server.